# Why did Suleiman build walls around Jerusalem?

Tags: jerusalem, ottoman

The [Old City of Jerusalem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_City_(Jerusalem)) is surrounded by pretty impressive walls built by [Suleiman the Magnificent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suleiman_the_Magnificent) in 1535–1542. The question is: why? Why build  walls around a city which is not on a border and did not have, as far as I can tell, any military significance for the Ottomans?

Or was some sort of Mameluk resurgence feared? Persian invasion?

Was this purely a vanity project?

Were there other similar projects of walling cities in the hinterland in the Ottoman empire?

Comment: It had religious significance though. The Portuguese were active in the area around that time, perhaps there is a connection.

Comment: I think this page from Israel’s Antiquities Authority answers your question: http://www.antiquities.org.il/jerusalemWalls/hstry_12_eng.asp

Comment: Supposedly Suleiman had a dream featuring lions, which he interpreted as divine direction to rebuild Jerusalem's walls. In practice it was probably to protect the city from Bedouin raids.

Comment: @JAsia I can't load that link; any chance you can summarize it in an answer?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: The quoted link boils down to: "*He rebuilt the walls for every reason you might imagine - and a couple more for good measure.*" Hardly definitive in either statement or reasoning.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace The key sentence is: "*To this day the reason the city walls were erected are still not known for certain. It is commonly believed, as E. Schiller and others have suggested, that the function of the city wall was not primarily military; rather it was meant to delimit the Holy City on the one hand, and protect its residents against raids by Bedouins and marauders on the other*". Then, as Pieter notes, a few alternative possibilities are mentioned.

Comment: To which I'd add that in pre-modern economies, it was the responsibility of the ruler to schedule work to ensure full employment; legitimacy was derived in part from a form of  labor monopsony (or more precisely a failure in the labor market reduced the legitimacy of rule).

Comment: @sempaiscuba, and/or J Asia - That seems like it was difficult enough to dig up and synthesize that its probably worthy of an answer...

Comment: T.E.D. Agreed, but I wasn't the one who found it, so any credit for an answer should probably go to @JAsia

Answer (score 5):

From **[Israel's Antiquities Authority](http://www.antiquities.org.il/jerusalemWalls/hstry_12_eng.asp)**:

> To this day the reason the city walls were erected are still not known
> for certain. It is commonly believed, as E. Schiller and others have
> suggested, that the function of the city wall was not primarily
> military; rather it was meant to delimit the Holy City on the one
> hand, and protect its residents against raids by Bedouins and
> marauders on the other. This is attested to by among other things, the
> thickness of the walls, which at just 2.5 m wide is substantially less
> than that of the Hasmonean city walls that were 4-5 meters thick, and
> this is despite the fact that at the time the walls were being built
> cannons were already an essential weapon in warfare.
>
> M. Ben-Dov proposes two other reasons for the construction of the city
> wall: 1) to protect against a renewed crusade by Carlos V, King of
> Spain, out of fear he wanted to conquer Jerusalem and 2) to reinforce
> Jerusalem from a religious standpoint so as to strengthen Muslim
> interests over the Christian interests in the city and thus "to win
> the encouragement of the vanquished Muslim population" (M. Ben-Dov
> 1983. P. 85). And in another place, "Jerusalem's fortifications were meant to promote the military goals of defending the city against
> powerful regular army forces and therefore their plan is excellent and
> many resources were invested in their construction. But no less
> important than this was the holiness of Jerusalem in the eyes of
> Islam… "(Ibid. p. 99)

References:

- On E. Schiller  - 1989 The Golan and the Battle of Gamla. In: M.
  Inbar, E. Schiller (eds.) Ramat Ha-Golan (Ariel 50–51):77–81 (Hebrew)
- On M Ben-Dov 1983 - The Western Wall (Hakotel) (Adama Books, 1983)

Complete *[list of references](http://www.antiquities.org.il/article_eng.aspx?sec_id=17&subj_id=296&id=526&module_id=)* from the site.

Comment: Also. if anyone is interested, the second of the listed references, [The Western Wall](https://archive.org/details/westernwall00bend/page/n5/mode/2up) by M Ben-Dov, is available to borrow from Internet Archive.

Comment: With all due respect, Ben-Dov seems to me to be off the track here. Charles V was barely holding his own with his own capital almost falling to Suleiman's army in 1529. And Jerusalem had been in Muslim hands for almost 300 years by then.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg - I have not read Ben-Dov’s book. I’m commenting based merely on my own opinion. Perhaps what Ben-Dov had in mind was the conflict between East vs West (Islam vs Christian) as both HR Emperor Charles V and Sultan Süleyman I were the respective faction leaders. Therefore, it didn’t matter that much what each individual armies strengths were at any one point, but the overall conflict during this time period.